# Problem reading some plugins: duplicate_plugin

Tags: rabbitmq, google-kubernetes-engine

I have three node rabbit MQ cluster deployed in Kubernetes following [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TbcQ.png). Server startup and running. But I got continuous error log as follows.

```
Problem reading some plugins: [{"/opt/rabbitmq/plugins/prometheus-4.3.0.ez",
                                duplicate_plugin}]
Problem reading some plugins: [{"/opt/rabbitmq/plugins/prometheus-4.3.0.ez",
                                duplicate_plugin}]
Problem reading some plugins: [{"/opt/rabbitmq/plugins/prometheus-4.3.0.ez",
                                duplicate_plugin}]
```

When I am checking plugins folder inside pod there are two prometheus versions as follows.

[image]

I removed prometheus-4.3.0.ez from plugins folder and again checked logs. Then error log not appear.

Image tag : 3.8

How I solve this issue. Is this effect to functions of rabbit-mq server ?
At least continuous log should remove, because we export logs to google cloud log storage. So log storage size and cost increasing rapidly.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TbcQ.png). https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/click-to-deploy/blob/master/k8s/rabbitmq/README.md#installation

Answer (score 1):

There should not be a problem deleting `prometheus-4.3.0.ez` from the plugins folder.  The image itself needs to be updated not to add that plugin as rabbitmq now includes a version of that plugin by default.